# Android LocationManager GPS Reading Never Changes While Screen is Off

Tags: android, gps, screen

I am trying to log a GPS location while the screen is off.

Here is my manifest file (note the WAKE_LOCK and GPS permissions as well as the LocationService definition):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joshuajwitter.backgroundgpstest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".BackgroundGPSTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".service.LocationService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.joshuajwitter.backgroundgpstest.service.LocationService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my background service:

```
package com.joshuajwitter.backgroundgpstest.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.util.Log;

    public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

    // the location manager and listener
    LocationManager m_locationManager;
    GPSLocationListener m_gpsLocationListener;

    // the dreaded wakelock
    WakeLock m_wakeLock;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting the LocationService");

        // acquire the wakelock
        Log.d(TAG, "Acquiring the wake lock");
        m_wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // get the wakelock
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        m_wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "String Wake Lock");

        // instantiate the gps listener
        m_gpsLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        // get the location manager
        m_locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // request location updates every 5 seconds
        m_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                5000, 0, m_gpsLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping the LocationService");

        // if the wakelock is held
        if (m_wakeLock.isHeld()) {

            // release it
            Log.d(TAG, "Releasing the wake lock");
            m_wakeLock.release();
        }

        // remove the listener
        m_locationManager.removeUpdates(m_gpsLocationListener);
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got a new location frome the LocationManager [" + location.getLatitude()
                    + ", " + location.getLongitude() + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

..and here is the activity that starts and stops the service:

```
package com.joshuajwitter.backgroundgpstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.joshuajwitter.backgroundgpstest.service.LocationService;

public class BackgroundGPSTestActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean m_serviceRunning = false;
    private Button m_mainButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // get the main button
        m_mainButton = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton));

        // set the main button listener
        m_mainButton
        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // if the service is not running
                if (!m_serviceRunning) {

                    // start the service
                    startService();
                }

                else {

                    // start the service
                    stopService();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startService() {

        m_serviceRunning = true;
        startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
        m_mainButton.setText("Stop Background GPS Service");
    }

    private void stopService() {

        m_serviceRunning = false;
        stopService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
        m_mainButton.setText("Start Background GPS Service");
    }
}
```

When I run the service and keep the screen on, I get the correct GPS latitude and longitude for my position. When I turn the screen off, however, I get the same repeating output:

```
01-31 15:48:58.467: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:48:59.467: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:49:00.467: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:49:01.467: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:49:02.477: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:49:03.477: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
01-31 15:49:04.467: D/LocationService(11752): Got a new location frome the LocationManager [-36.879621, -7.734375]
```

When I turn the screen back on, I get correct GPS values once more. Here's the kicker: Google Maps Navigation runs on my phone with the screen off. If I run it at the same time as my test program, the same behavior occurs... the Navigation app gets notified of the correct coordinates while my test app repeats the same lat/long over and over.

This is on an Android phone running 2.3.3 Gingerbread. Thanks for any input!

Comment: So if the device is awake you're getting different coordinates each time it is logged?

Comment: Can I ask, is this is Motorola phone? I'm getting a lot of users report no GPS activity when the screen is off.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this. Seems to be common across a few phones. Endomondo claim to have fixed it, and Google Maps can clearly work around it. Unfortunately I'm completely unable to reproduce it myself. :(

Comment: Have the same problem. How do you know Google Maps gets around it? The only way you can tell is if Google Maps is running and shows you your current location, which means you have to have the screen on.